# Handle string or int in server object extension

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-server, c#, arcgis-rest-api, server-object-extension

How would you also check to see if the value you are passing into into an SOE is an integer as well?

This checks for string, but returns 0 when passing number:

```
string searchValStr;
int searchValInt;

found = operationInput.TryGetString("searchVal", out searchValStr);
        if (!found || string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchValStr))
            // check for int
            Int32.TryParse("searchVal", out searchValInt);
```

How would I check for int and string using same input?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string searchValStr;
int searchValInt;

found = operationInput.TryGetString("searchVal", out searchValStr);
        if (!found || string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchValStr))

            // check for int
            bool isNum = Int32.TryParse("searchVal", out searchValInt); 
            if (isNum)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("input is an int");
            }

            else
            {
                Messagebox.Show("input is not an int");
            }
```